# Style Basedon not working with checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a style defined in a resource dictionary to make my checkbox look like a button:

```
<Style TargetType="CheckBox" x:Key="CBCheckBoxButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <Border Name="BackgroundBorder" Background="Black" CornerRadius="20">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="UpperRect" Margin="1" Grid.Row="0" RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Fill="{StaticResource GrayGradient}"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="ButtonContent" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="UpperRect" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource LightBlueGradient}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="UpperRect" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource BlueGradient}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="BackgroundBorder" Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource ShadowEffect}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
            <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource DisableShadowEffect}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When used like so it works great:

```
<CheckBox Width="80" Height="80" Margin="10" Content="{Binding Y2LockAxisString}" Command="{Binding Y2LockDisableEnableCommand}" Style="{StaticResource CBCheckBoxButton}"/>
```

But I need to add a style so that different commands etc. are called depending on the state of the check box. So I used the basedon property:

```
<CheckBox Width="80" Height="80" Margin="10">
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource CBCheckBoxButton}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ExecuteX2LockDisable}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ExecuteX2LockEnable}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox>
```

But the checkbox looks like a default checkbox with none of the appearance elements applied to it.

Why isn't the appearance style working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are adding the `Style` as `Content`, instead of `Style`.

Have you tried

```
<CheckBox Width="80" Height="80" Margin="10">
    <CheckBox.Style>
         <Style --- snip --->
         </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, You were correct! As soon as I saw your answer I saw what was going on. I was looking for a more difficult cause.